# How to Speed Up Flag Procces (Update Data) in foreach using php?

Tags: php

i have data in foreach. The data entered in the foreac will be given a 'Y' flag. If the data is small, the flag process runs normally. But if the data is big, the flag process is very slow.

How to speed up flag processing inside foreach ?

my code :

```
 foreach ($results as $key=>$row) {
        $data[$key]         = $row;
        $data[$key]['_id']  = (string) Application_Helper_General::generateIdJsonFile();

        $queryUdateMemberFlag = 'UPDATE M_MEMBER SET SYNC_FLAG = "Y" WHERE MEMBER_ID = '.$row['MEMBER_ID'].'';
        $db->query($queryUdateMemberFlag);
    }
```

Comment: WHERE field IN (1, 2, 3)

Comment: `UPDATE M_MEMBER SET SYNC_FLAG = "Y" WHERE MEMBER_ID In( your_ids_comma_separated)`

Comment: `if the data is big`?, What are we talking about `thousands` or `millions`? Share the `table-schema`, DB details; How many records are there in that `table` & how much time does it take for `big-data`(large #updates)?.

Comment: Maybe it's best to start with the [tour] and to read [ask]. With the little info you provide, it's impossible to tell what is going on. Also, it would help if you provided a [mcve]. That said, "slow" is always an interpretation, what are the numbers? Also, if you wonder why something runs slowly, you need to understand where it spends its time exactly, which is called "profiling". Do some research on that topic, too.